# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1538956627792"

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

I'm trying to convert the system time to `int` with the following code:

```
String today = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();
int todayInt = Integer.parseInt(today);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1538956627792"
```

Why is this number: `"1538956627792"` still throwing an error?

Comment: Why didn't you just do `int todayInt = System.currentTimeMillis();`?

Comment: https://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/language/java-data.html maybe you are above the size of integer?

Comment: long todayLong = System.currentTimeMillis();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Number is too long to be parsed as `int`, You need to use `Long` to parse that big number,

```
long todayInt = Long.parseLong(today);
```

Answer (score 3):

The size of `int` type is 32 bit, it ranges from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`.
**1538956627792** exceeds the range, so the error caused.

you could change `int` to `long` to solve this problem, here is [a detailed reference](https://cs.fit.edu/%7Eryan/java/language/java-data.html)